# El procedimiento o la funcion, no recibe el parametro

Tags: c#, .net

tengo un gridView del cual quiero borrar la fila seleccionado mediante el evento RowDeleting. Tengo un procedimiento creado para ello, pero me dice que no recibe el parametro que le estoy pasando.

'Este es el codigo del gridView'

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdControlPlanificacionPreventiva" AutoGenerateDeleteButton="true" 
OnRowDeleting="grdControlPlanificacionPreventiva_RowDeleting" runat="server" AutoGenerateSelectButton="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="grdControlPlanificacionPreventiva_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:GridView>
```

'Este es el codigo del RowDeleting'

```
protected void grdControlPlanificacionPreventiva_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
    {
                    cmdDeletePlanificacionPreventiva.Connection = conexion;

        int idPlanificacion;
        conexion.Open();
        idPlanificacion = int.Parse(grdControlPlanificacionPreventiva.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Text);
        prmDeleteIdPlanificacionPreventiva.Value = idPlanificacion;
        prmDeleteIdPlanificacionPreventiva.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.SmallInt;
        prmDeleteIdPlanificacionPreventiva.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        cmdDeletePlanificacionPreventiva.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p_deleteIdPlanificacionPreventiva", idPlanificacion);
        cmdDeletePlanificacionPreventiva.ExecuteNonQuery();
        try
        {
            cmdDeletePlanificacionPreventiva.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch(Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
        conexion.Close();
    }
```

'Este es el procedimiento'

```
create procedure [cdt].[pr_deletePlanificacionPreventiva]
@p_idPlanificacionPreventiva smallint
as
begin
    delete 
    from cdt.PlanificacionPreventiva
    where @p_idPlanificacionPreventiva=IdPlanificacionPreventiva
end
```

Comment: Donde creaste prmDeleteIdPlanificacionPreventiva, parece que creas dos veces el parametro. asegurate que idPlanificacion no es nulo

Comment: el idPlanificacion si que recibe el id seleccionado asi que eso va bien.

Comment: Tienes un pequeño follón de parámetros creados prmDeleteIdPlanificacionPreventiva, prmIdPlanificacionPreventiva y AddWithValue("@p_idPlanificacionPreventiva", idPlanificacion)

Comment: Tu código debería funcionar salvo que hayas añadido prmIdPlanificacionPreventiva al comando cmdDeletePlanificacionPreventiva porque no iniciaste el valor

Comment: Si me he dado cuenta despues que lo tenia mal creado ahora lo modifico.

Answer (score 0):

Como pasar un parámetro a un comando y capturar bien las excepciones:

```
     protected void grdControlPlanificacionPreventiva_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
                {int idPlanificacion;
                 SqlParameter prmIdPlanificacion = new SqlParameter();
                 prmIdPlanificacion.ParameterName = "@p_idPlanificacionPreventiva";
                    
                    cmdDeletePlanificacionPreventiva.Connection = conexion;
                    prmIdPlanificacion.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.SmallInt;
                    prmIdPlanificacion.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                                  
                    try
                    {conexion.Open(); 
                    idPlanificacion = int.Parse(grdControlPlanificacionPreventiva.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Text);
                    prmIdPlanificacion .Value = idPlanificacion;
                    cmdDeletePlanificacionPreventiva.Parameters.Add (prmIdPlanificacion);
                    cmdDeletePlanificacionPreventiva.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                    catch(Exception ex)
                    {
                       Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                    }
                    conexion.Close();
                }
```

Comment: He probado el codigo y sigue sin realizar la delete. Ahora no me visualiza ningun error y he podido comprobar que el prmDeleteIdPlanificacion ahora si que tenia el id seleccionado.

Comment: he creado prmIdPlanificacionPreventiva en la funcion, pero ten cuidado de no haber añadido un parametro antes al comando